# How to create a Google bigquery Partition table from Select query in Airflow Dag?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have this query that generates a partition table if I run it in bigquery.

```
CREATE TABLE my_dataset.processed_table
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(export_id, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, n, 1))
CLUSTER BY export_id
AS (
  SELECT *, CAST(FLOOR(n*RAND()) AS INT64) AS export_id
  FROM my_dataset.source_table
);
```

Can someone please help me how can I execute this in airflow dag and create a partition table from a source table.

The actual google doc from where I got this query:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#limit_the_exported_file_size